# How to remove all rows after specific event occurrence in r

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello all my dataset looks like

```
PID event
123 1
123 2
123 1
123 3
123 4
111 2
111 3
111 4
111 5
133 1
133 2
133 3
144 1
144 3
144 4
144 5
166 1
166 2
177 2
177 3
```

I need to remove previous rows or PID after the event occurence  of 3 in the dataset

My expected result :

```
PID event
123 3
123 4
111 3
111 4
111 5
133 3
144 3
144 4
144 5
177 3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `dplyr::filter(dataset, event >= 3)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(PID) %>% filter(cumany(event==3))
```

Comment: You'll need to `group_by(PID)` first to get the expected output I think

Answer (score 0):

Simply by

```
data[data$event >= "3",]
```